# Using Variables inside PHP for creating a JSONTable

Tags: php, json, google-visualization

I tried to fetch data from table gainfinal and display the data in a JSON_Table for the visualization in a google API chart. I have particularly used two variables $countryone and $countrytwo. They have been used as in the code below. Everything Else is working fine. And output of the code is like this

```
{"cols":[{"label":"year","type":"string"},{"label":".$countryone.","type":"number"},{"label":".$countrytwo.","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"1995"},{"v":"76.8561073"},{"v":"46.8550182"}]},{"c":[{"v":"1996"},{"v":"77.0366637"},{"v":"47.1409752"}]},{"c":[{"v":"1997"},{"v":"77.180129"},{"v":"46.6331669"}]}
```

In the second and third column, I need the actual value of the variable printed ( I mean, USA and NPL ) but it just prints the variable as I string. How can I correct it ?

```
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
    $username = "root"; 
    $password = "";   
    $host = "localhost";
    $database="climate";

    $countryone='USA'; 
    $countrytwo='NPL';
    $index ='gainfinal'; 


    $server = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
    $connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

    $myquery = "SELECT  `year`, 

        sum(case when `countrycode` = '$countryone' then `values` else 0 end) AS `countryone`,
        sum(case when `countrycode` = '$countrytwo' then `values` else 0 end) AS `countrytwo`

FROM   `$index`
GROUP BY `year`
";
    $query = mysql_query($myquery);
    $table = array();
    $table['cols'] = array(
    /* define your DataTable columns here
     * each column gets its own array
     * syntax of the arrays is:
     * label => column label
     * type => data type of column (string, number, date, datetime, boolean)
     */
    array('label' => 'year', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => '.$countryone.', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => '.$countrytwo.', 'type' => 'number'),


    // etc...
);
    $rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $temp = array();
    // each column needs to have data inserted via the $temp array
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['year']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['countryone']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['countrytwo']);


    // etc...

    // insert the temp array into $rows
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}
// populate the table with rows of data
$table['rows'] = $rows;

// encode the table as JSON
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

// set up header; first two prevent IE from caching queries
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

// return the JSON data
echo $jsonTable;
?>
```

Comment: Don't wrap your vars in quotes.  Or If you need them use doubles like  "\"$countryone\""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either remove the single quotes around your variable name, or use double quotes. Single quotes do not parse variables inside them like doubles do:

```
array('label' => 'year', 'type' => 'string'),
array('label' => $countryone, 'type' => 'number'),
array('label' => $countrytwo, 'type' => 'number'),
```

...or:

```
array('label' => 'year', 'type' => 'string'),
array('label' => "$countryone", 'type' => 'number'),
array('label' => "$countrytwo", 'type' => 'number'),
```

The way you are currently doing it (`'.$countryone.'`) is interpreting it as a string literally resulting in `'.$countryone.'`. If you changed this to double quotes, you'd still get the periods on either side e.g. `.USA.` as `".$countryone."` would parse the variable for its literal value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Here, I also tried the same and it worked. Thank you again.